# C#: Task Factory starts task repeatedly?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a probably simple question about the task factory. I have to following code:

In this task is a loop that is polling data from the RS232 and a counter that stops polling after 10 times. After this "doCollect" will be set to false.

And now comes the strange thing: The task runs repeatedly. The caller code is:

```
// class Main()
RS232DataAquisition _RS232DataAquisition = new RS232DataAquisition();

public override void Run()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timeout = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    timeout.Start();

    _RS232DataAquisition.Start();

    while ((timeout.ElapsedMilliseconds <= (dataGatherTime_inSeconds * 1000)) && _RS232DataAquisition.DoCollect)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    timeout.Stop();

    _RS232DataAquisition.Stop();
}
```

Per my understanding the Run() function should start the thread and return into the while-loop waiting for the thread to finish. But it never does?!

Here's the code for ReadDataFromRS232:

```
// sealed class RS232DataAquisition
private bool doCollect = false;

public bool DoCollect
{
    get { return doCollect; }
}

public void Start()
{
    doCollect = true;

    currentTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        this.ReadDataFromRS232();
    });
}

private void ReadDataFromRS232(int NumtoRead = 10)
{
    var port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(PortName);
    int waitCount = 5;

    var portExists = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames().Any(x => x == PortName);

    if (!portExists)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Port does not exist!");
    }

    while (port.IsOpen && waitCount-- > 0)
    {
        doCollect = false;
        Wait();
    }

    doCollect = true;

    if (!port.IsOpen)
    {
        port.Open();
        port.NewLine = _NewLine;
        port.ReadTimeout = 2000;
        int number;

        try { }
        finally { }

        port.Write("flashon\r");

        while (doCollect && (_readCounter <= NumtoRead))
        {
            string s;

            try
            {
                s = port.ReadLine();
            }
            catch
            {
                s = "-1";
            }

            int i;

            if (int.TryParse(s, out i))
            {
                number = Convert.ToInt32(s, 10);
            }
            else
            {
                number = 0;
            }

            lock (thisLock) _data.Add(number);

            _readCounter++;
        }

        port.Write("flashoff\r");

        port.Close();

        port.Dispose();

        Wait(); Wait();
    }
}

private void Wait()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait(1);
}
```

I don't get, why "ReadDataFromRS232" is beeing repeated until the timeout stops this task.

Thank you for any help :)

**EDIT: Added some missing code.**

Comment: Where do you set `doCollect` to `false`?

Comment: (I got this code from a former employee). He sets it in the "Stop()" function after the timeout. However - shouldn't it make any difference? Even having this property set I don't see the influence on why the task calls this function repeatedly

Comment: Well... `Stop` function is called after loop, so loop will go forever. It is obvious.

Comment: Thx odyss-jii. But why is this obvious? Per my understanding the task should stop after reaching the end of the function (what it does after 10 iterations)?!

Comment: 1) What is `Wait` and why do you use it so frequently? 2) How `doCollect` is declared? If it isn't `volatile`, second `while` in `ReadDataFromRS232` won't see, that `doCollect` was changed from another thread; 3) Sequential call of `port.Close` and `port.Dispose` isn't required. Moreover, I'd wrap `port` into `using` block.

Comment: Hi Dennis. I'll edit the main post. I suppose I missed copying it.

Comment: @odyss-jii: at first look, `Run` should stop reading after timeout. It seems to me, it's a multi-threading issue: `private bool doCollect`.

Comment: It might be a multi-threading issue. I suppose the former code simply ran each time in the timeout and so nobody noticed that it's not working... Within this project there's almost nothing that can surprise me anymore -.-

Comment: That is true. @AllDayPiano: When you say that `ReadDataFromRS232` is being repeated, do you mean that there are actual calls to method? Can you stack trace the invocation?

Comment: @AllDayPiano: at least, `private bool doCollect` must be `private volatile bool doCollect`. See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx . `Wait` is just a trash and must be thrown away, I suppose, that this is a "way" to workaround some device behavior.

Comment: Ok, then I'll throw wait away. I either didn't understand where this delay of 10ms and another 1ms (with the ability for the os to interrupt) should lead to.

Comment: It's absolutely weird but now it's not working again. The thread continues after a while randomly even though it should be already finished?! I think I'll throw the whole code away!

Answer (score 0):

As Dennis said the problem seemed to come from the missing volatile. It works now even though I have no idea why it didn't before.